# can JIT optimize such unnecessary call?

Tags: java, optimization, jit

I have question about JIT optimization.
I compiled a simple piece of code:

```
class btest
{
        static final boolean flag=false;

        public final void foo(int x)
        {
                if(flag) {a=x; b=x*2; c=x*3;}
        }

        public void bar(int y)  {foo(y);}

        int a,b,c;
};
```

`flag` is set to `false` so `foo()` is perfectly compiled to empty code - just returns.
But `bar()` still calls it.

Is it possible that JIT will eliminate this call?
Does it matter if `flag` belongs to external class?

regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can eliminate it and inline it in code.

Note: It can also do this for non-volatile non-final variables where it thinks the thread doesn't change the value.  A common mistake is something like

```
boolean running = true;

public void run() {
     while(running) {
        // do something
     }
}

public void stop() {
     running = false;
}
```

A common misconception is that the thread might keep running for an while but stop at some unknown point, when actually the JIT might inline `running` and never stop.

Comment: Why just non-final? Aren't final variables more open to said optimization?

Comment: @hexafraction It will do it for primitive final variables, and some non-final variables.

Comment: So, do You think that it is better idea to use for conditional compilation if-s wrapped in methods (like my example) instead if-s on top level, what is less convenient and probably less elegant?

Comment: @ardabro you can do either. I suspect it won't make much difference.  Either way it gets eliminated. Empty methods get inlined.

Answer (score 1):

The JIT compiler would most likely be able to eliminate this.

But actually, I think that the `if` statement is likely to be optimized away *before* then.  The reason is in [JLS 14.21](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) starting at the point where is says this:

> *"However, in order to allow the if statement to be used conveniently for "conditional compilation" purposes, the actual rules differ."*

If goes on to say that that the compiler (that is the bytecode compiler!) may generate different code in your example depending on the known value of the condition at compile time.

Note that this special treatment only applies to `if` statements, and only if the condition is a *constant expression*.  (That term has a very specific meaning - see [JLS 15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28))  If you tried the same "trick" with a `while` loop for example, you would get a compilation error complaining about unreachable code.

(This "conditional compilation" special treatment goes back to the early days of Java, and is part of the rationale for Gosling *et al*'s decision to not include a preprocessor in the Java language.)